# Basing case on result of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, aggregate-functions

Due to some very specific circumstances, I've found myself having to write a query like this (example simplified):

```
SELECT username, avg(points) as average_points,
  CASE 
    WHEN average_points >= 100
      THEN TRUE
      ELSE FALSE
  END as is_winner
FROM user_points
GROUP BY username;
```

Of course I cannot do this, since average_points isn't a column. Is there a way to do something that would actually achieve this in a single query?

I thought about using a subquery but I have to calculate the points and the boolean for each user separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the expression. There is also no need for a `CASE`:

```
SELECT username, 
       avg(points) as average_points,
       avg(points) >= 100 as is_winner
FROM user_points
GROUP BY username;
```

The `avg(points)` will only be evaluated once if you are concerned about performance.

Another option is to put this into a derived table:

```
SELECT username, 
       average_points,
       average_points >= 100 as is_winner
FROM (
   select username, avg(points) as average_points
   from user_points
   group by username
) pt;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT username, avg(points) as average_points,
  CASE 
    WHEN avg(points) >= 100
      THEN TRUE
      ELSE FALSE
  END as is_winner
FROM user_points
GROUP BY username;
```